# Strange behaviour with svg path

Tags: svg

Consider the following svg code:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<path d="M 180 100 C 180 105 180 120 182 120 " stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="3"></path>

</svg>
```

My browser (chrome) renders it as follows. Note the weird "pacman" effect at the end of the path.

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: maybe we should close the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the line width is large in relation to the "tightness" of the curve, as is the case in your path definition, odd rendering effects may happen.

Please refer to section **13.5.7. Computing the shape of the stroke** of the [svg spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperties) for details:

> Authors should be aware that the shape of a stroke may in some cases, such as at extremely tight curves, differ across platforms.
>   [image: Image showing how stroke shape differs across platforms.]

---

For why this may be happening, think of this shape as a self-intersecting, filled polygon and consider it being rendered using the `oddeven` rule for `fill` (See section **13.4.2. Winding rule: the ‘fill-rule’ property**).

---

Here's an exaggerated version of your curve using a line width of 50 to illustrate this behaviour:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<path d="M 180 100 C 180 105 180 120 182 120 " stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="50"></path>

</svg>
```

---

Finally, here is a visualization of a "thin, wide brush" painting the very bottom of your shape.  Specifically note how it backtracks over an already painted area towards the end of the line.

[image]

... and here is just the *perimeter* of the shape made with the two tips of a "thin, wide brush":

[image]